# Algorithm to batch individual cells into blocks based on attribute

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

This is a real world algorithms problem I came across while coding an application for excel.

The background:
In excel, we have to write color information to the sheet one cell at a time - there are no array methods. Moreover the act of adding a fill color to a cell is computationally slow. The *one* exception to this is that, if an entire block of cells are to be the same color, then we can write them in a batch. E.g., if cells A1, A2, B1, B2 are all to be colored green (or all the same RGB tuple), we can do code of the form

```
Range(A1:B2).color = Green
```

When implementing some user functionality, I will often be either implementing some color scheme, or copying some of the user's color data to elsewhere (the cost of reading color data can be quite low, it is only writing new data which is slow, on the order of 0.02s).

The problem is then, given a dictionary which maps color tuples to lists of individual cells, say something along the lines of

```
{Green : ["A1", "B1", "C3","C4", "A2", "D3", "D4"],
Blue : ["H3", "H4", "Z6"],
...}
```

How can we best batch the data into 'blocks' to write the colors to excel? I.e. minimising the total number of blocks.

E.g., in the above example, we might do "A1:B1", "C3:D4", "A2" as the blocks for green.

If it is helpful the data in the dictionary can be ordered in some way, e.g. added in rows and cells in order, so that we could have

```
Green: [["A1","B1"], ["A2"], ["C3","D3"], ["C4","D4"]]
```

My thoughts:
The simplest algorithm is probably some kind of greedy algorithm, e.g., we go as far along as we can with one color, and then we go as many rows down as we can. This is in fact the approach I am currently implementing, but I was curious if there are smarter solutions out there.

Comment: Maybe useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table will let you quickly compute, given a particular rectangle and a color c, how many cells in that rectangle have color c.

Comment: I will have a think. I could also post in Theoretical Computer Science stack exchange if the question would be more appropriate for there?

Comment: Please pick one site where you want this to appear -- I'd ask you to avoid cross-posting.  I don't think this is going to be well-received on TCS.SE.  You have a practical problem, and they are more interested in CS theory.